# How to implement web service transactions?

Tags: java, distributed-transactions

Is there a Java tool for choreographing web services that makes it easy to deal with transactions?

In my use case I want to chain 2 SOAP web services: the first will perform a debit into a client's bank account and the second will recharge his cell phone for the corresponding amount. How can I implement this sequence of web services calls transactionally?

I briefly looked at Apache Camel but it doesn't seem to be the most adequate tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these your web-services? Are they implemented using SOAP or REST?

Comment: These are SOAP web services.

Comment: google WS-AtomicTransaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your web-services are implemented using SOAP, you can implement 2-phase commit with WS-AtomicTransaction extension. These articles go into details how it can be implemented:

- [Using Web Services Atomic Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13734/transaction.htm) (Java)
- [Coordinating Web Services Activities with WS-Coordination,
  WS-AtomicTransaction, and WS-BusinessActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms996526.aspx#wsac_topic4) (.NET, but the
  concept is the same)

Comment: The first link seems to be weblogic-specific. In my case we will be using JBoss so I was wondering if this is the tool I should use http://narayana.jboss.org/.

Comment: @dmz73 I don't have experience with it, but after having a glance Narayana seems to be a natural choice for JBoss deployments.

Comment: @dmz73, were you able to successfully implement the distributed transaction with WS-AT on JBoss (or any other platform)? We have JBoss EAP 6.3 and avoid distributed transactions, but here and there it's unavoidable. We've used EJBs in that case, but would like to know if it works with SOAP services.